# 'mat-placeholder' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been updating angular material 8 to latest version (15), but now I'm having the next error at  the moment to type `npm start`:

> 'mat-placeholder' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-placeholder' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-placeholder' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I tried to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` but is not working.

Anyone know what I have to do here?

I added `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to the Angular module but it is not working. I need to migrate that `mat-placeholder` but I don't know what is missing.

I'm using:

```html
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
    <input
        matInput
        readonly
    />
    <mat-placeholder class="date-placeholder"
    >Select date</mat-placeholder
>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 5):

[`<mat-placeholder>` has been deprecated since Angular Material v6](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-placeholder-attribute-and-child-element-were-both-specified).

> The `<mat-placeholder>` element is deprecated, you should use `placeholder` for placeholders and `<mat-label>` for labels.

[Angular Material v15 recommends setting the `placeholder` attribute on the input](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#placeholder). Additionally, binding to `floatLabel` [no longer accepts `'never'`](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#form-field).

> The `floatLabel` input no longer accepts `'never'`. `floatLabel="never"` was only supported by the legacy form-field appearance which has been dropped. It was used to achieve a floating label that behaved like a placeholder. If you need this behavior, use the `placeholder` property on `<input>` instead.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input
        matInput
        readonly
        placeholder="Select date"
    />
>
</mat-form-field>
```

---

You are likely running into this error now because Angular Material v15 is a major refactor of the library [towards MDC-based components](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration).

It's possible the functionality is temporarily available by importing `MatLegacyFormFieldModule` instead of `MatFormFieldModule`.